# What WP 8.1 XAML control could look and behave like the system Task switcher?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, custom-controls

I'm writing a Windows Phone 8.1 Store app and I need to create a control so that it looks and behaves similar to WP 8.1 system task switcher (that appears when holding back hardware button).

It should show some images and support sliding left or right when swiping. Does anyone know what control should I use or do I need to create a completely new control from scratch?

Comment: There are none available and it also violates the marketplace guidelines. So if you're doing an enterprise app, you can roll your own :)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use the HUB control. You can create Hubs dynamically or even make them data bound

Comment: I don't think it violates marketplace guidelines because UC Browser has similar control.

Comment: The idea of using the Hub control is interesting, thanks. I should give it a try. I think the other way is to use something like ScrollViewer with horizontal scrolling or modification of Pivot.

Comment: you may take a look at something like Syncfusion's Carousel control: http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the sollution was easy. The control I was looking for was... a ScrollViewer. It has 2 properties in WinRT XAML that make the ScrollViewer scrolling behave like I wanted: `HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment` and `HorizontalSnapPointsType`.

If you want to try this behavior, [this MSDN code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-ScrollViewer-pan-and-949d29e9) will expose it for you.

One point to mention. If you wish to set such behavior to, for example, a ListView you should firstly get its internal ScrollViewer in code and then set its `HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment` and `HorizontalSnapPointsType` properties. You can use `GetFirstDescendantOfType<T>()` extension method from WinRT XAML toolkit.

```
var sv = myListView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
sv.HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment = SnapPointsAlignment.Center;
sv.HorizontalSnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.Mandatory;
```